# Slideshow of three divs like a filmstrip using jquery help required

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I need to make a slideshow just like at is here :    http://www.xo.com

I have tried using jquery cycle plugin on three divs adjucent to each other with differnt widths, and one id of all the three divs also but alfter some time these start to slide arbitaray, i need the three divs slide like a film strip as is at xo.com.

Please help.

All the divs essentialy has the same images just to give it the impression of a filmstrip. If anyone has a better idea it is more than welcome please.

Heres the code that i cycle the images with, but they sync out after some time.

```
$('.images').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
    })

<div style="width:160px;float: left; overflow: hidden;">
<div class="images">
    <img src="images/slides/1.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/2.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/3.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/4.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/5.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/6.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/7.jpg">
</div>
</div>

<div class="width: 1024px;overflow: hidden;float: left;">
<div class="images">
    <img src="images/slides/1.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/2.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/3.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/4.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/5.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/6.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/7.jpg">
</div>
</div>

<div class="width: 160px;overflow: hidden;float: left;">
<div class="images">
    <img src="images/slides/1.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/2.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/3.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/4.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/5.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/6.jpg">
    <img src="images/slides/7.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your codes in your question.

Comment: i have included my code

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "they synch out after some time." Any error in the debugger console? Might as well include your HTML codes too.

Comment: by 'out of sync' i mean that when the slideshow run they run differently, i need to run these three divs cotaining same images but arranged differently so that these three div images cycle 'scrollHorz' and give the impression that image comes form 1st goes into second div and then in the thrid div. but when this program runs, after some minutes the timing of these divs are out, meaning that first div has some other image second has osmeother and third has someother, they do not div the impression of one div with scrollling images, basically i need that first and last act as a next and prev

Comment: Include your HTML codes, or better yet, set up a [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) if you can.

Comment: added the stack snippet please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 duplicated `<div class="images">` blocks are probably why your images end up stepping on each other's toes. Remember, the `<img>` elements are the ones representing the images, the `<div>`s are the blocks containing these images.

Try run my codes below where I removed all the duplication. See if they do what you want.

```js
(function($){
  $('#slideshow-1').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    speed: 300,
    timeout: 2000
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<div id="slideshow-1">
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
```

Comment: the answer that you gave is for one slideshow which i know can be done with one 'image' div as per code. but i need to have an effect like the one that this website's homepage slidshow has 'http://www.xo.com'. your given code has one div that conatins the img elements and cycle them, but i need somehting like on this website that i mentioned please. it will be like previous and next images are displaying.

Comment: They are using something called carousel. There are a few options [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/).